# Delphi - Transform Dataset to XML using xtr

Tags: xml, delphi, dataset, delphi-10.1-berlin

Need to export an XML from a Query Dataset based on an XTR generated from XMLMapper tool.

I have the following:

- MSSQL database with Tables: Patients, PatientAllergies (1-n relation)
- Components: TFDConnection -> FDQueryPatients,FDQUeryPatientAllergies -> DSPPatients -> CDSPatients -> DSPatients
- I followed a tutorial to make the PatientAllergies a nested dataset inside the CDSPatients so that 1-n relation would show correctly.
- I created a transformation file xtr to transform the CDSPatients to XML, and everything shows correctly ([XTR File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Ilf-zNw3G7UVpfazB5YkRqSjA/view?usp=sharing)) (See picture)[image: XMLMapper]

Now how can I use this CDSet to output an xml using this xtr file created?
I researched a lot and all tutorials show how to transform an existing XML file into Datapacket, or how to manipulate XML and apply updates using XMLTransformProvider. I DO NOT want to the provider of the CDSPatients to point to the XMLTransformProvider since I need it to point to the Query which fetches the data from DB.
What I need is exactly what happens with the following, but programatically: When you select the Document in the XMLMapper, and save the document, the output is the XML file I need (See picture)
[image]

Thanks

Comment: added the Xtr screenshot

Comment: Ok, but a screenshot is not much help to a reader wishing to use the file.

Comment: Added link to XTR file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be as simple as:

- Drop an XMLTransformClient
- Assign XMLTransformClient.ProviderName to the datasetprovider DSPPatients (No need to pass through the clientdataset)
- Call the function with the parameter XTR file generated with the XMLMapper 
  `memo1.Lines.Text := XMLTransformClient1.GetDataAsXml('ToXml.xtr');`